# Netsuite: How to show PO for only those with credit approval?

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, under Setup > Site Builder > Set Up Website on the shopping tab there's a checkbox for "Display Purchase Order Field on Payment Info Page"

We definitely want to allow customers to be able to pay with a PO, but only customers who have passed a credit check and have agreed upon terms.

Is there a way to configure NS to only show it for those who are approved? Or do I have to write custom code to make this type of logic work?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

1. Disable the PO visibility in setup so that all customers do not see a PO.
2. Have terms customers place the order normally without charging them, and on confirmation of the order, send the PO in a system generated email.

Terms customers don't have to pay immediately, so it's an easier work-around than adding a script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually posted a slightly different question. I didn't ask the question specifically enough to get the answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your site setup on the Shopping tab set the Sales Order Type to "Per Customer Basis". The PO entry and opportunity to select terms will only be shown to customers with terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually posted a slightly different question. I didn't ask the question specifically enough to get the answers I was looking for.